# Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I am using

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

for register jquery in Yii 1 top of script but in page
added last of scripts? why?

Comment: "top of script" - which script? The one called? The view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coreScriptPosition` for this.

Directly from the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#coreScriptPosition-detail):

> Where the scripts registered using registerCoreScript or
>   registerPackage will be inserted in the page. This can be one of the
>   CClientScript::POS_* constants. Defaults to CClientScript::POS_HEAD.

Use like this:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->coreScriptPosition = CClientScript::POS_HEAD;
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

Another useful [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/572/how-to-include-javascript-css/) to read on this. (Read the comments too)

--Edit--

You can tell `Yii` where to put the script in the method:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(string $id, string $script, integer $position=NULL, array $htmlOptions=array ( ));
```

The `$position` variable will be the position of the script on your page.

And can be any of these:

- `CClientScript::POS_HEAD` : the script is inserted in the head section right before the title element.
- `CClientScript::POS_BEGIN` : the script is inserted at the beginning of the body section.
- `CClientScript::POS_END` : the script is inserted at the end of the body section.
- `CClientScript::POS_LOAD` : the script is inserted in the window.onload() function.
- `CClientScript::POS_READY` : the script is inserted in the jQuery's ready function.

Comment: include(ClientScript.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @HoseinHamedan, should be `CClientScript`, my bad.